# Separate key:value-string to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

I have a string like this:

```
"(list:\"RTM API\" status:completed)"
```

And I want to convert it into a NSDictionary with the "value" before the colon as the key and the value left of the colon as the value - like this:

```
list: "RTM API"
status: "completed"
```

It can probably be done using a simple regex or so, but I don't really know how to do that.
I hope someone can explain a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get a the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:
(\w+)\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"

Note that this won't work with keys that have spaces or special characters. Only a-zA-Z0-9 (words). Plus you ALWAYS have to have quotes around values.

This will return two sets of results, one with all keys and one with all values.

I hope this helps.